# VBA-Extracting header of a comment

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to write a code, where every comment of a **word**-document will be extracted into an excel sheet AND the belonging chapter/heading it is written in.

The Code actually works but I have no clue how to get the chapter. It should be the number of the chapter like 1 or 1.1 and so on.
Does anybody has a clue?

```
'set a reference to the Excel object library 

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add ' create a new workbook
With xlWB.Worksheets(1)
        .Cells(1, 2).Formula = "author"
        .Cells(1, 3).Formula = "site"
        .Cells(1, 4).Formula = "comment"
        .Cells(1, 1).Formula = "date"
        .Cells(1, 5).Formula = "chapter"
        .Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
    .Cells(i + 1, 2).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Contact
    .Cells(i + 1, 3).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Scope.Paragraphs(1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    .Cells(i + 1, 4).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Range
    .Cells(i + 1, 1).Formula = Format(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    .Cells(i + 1, 5).Formula = ???????? (Code to show the heading)
Next i

    .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter
End With
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: chapter of what?  Excel doesn't have chapters. Is this for Word?  It appears that your code is incomplete. (Also, welcome! Check out then [tour] - to earn your first badge! - also see "[ask]", and how to create a [mcve])

Comment: It is a word document, and with the code i extract the comments into an excel sheet.

Comment: Your code misses the initialization of `ActiveDocument` ?

Comment: actually it works like this

Comment: I added the tag `ms-word` because this macro seems to be used in ms-word.